# Android Studio 4.1 upgrade gives Flutter some error

Tags: android-studio, flutter

After updating to Android Studio 4.1, Flutter (1.22.0) seems a mess.

1. Building app gives error `ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.`
2. Running `flutter doctor` gives error `Android toolchain - Could not determine java version` and `Android Studio (not installed)`
3. Switch to `flutter channel dev` gives error `git: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/stable':`
4. Running `flutter upgrade` doesn't do anything, cursor seems idle for quite long time.

Any "stable" solution for this? (please not "hack" solution that needs to fix again later)

I can't work, feels sad.

Comment: You have to update the path to Java in your path variables.

Answer (score 0):

The right and stable answer is to wait for `flutter upgrade` to run. You don't need to hack anything. It will then upgrade to Flutter 1.22.2

Note:

1. I wait for almost 2 minutes to see some text that it runs.
2. You may need `flutter upgrade --force` to run it.
3. The upgrade process somehow feels way slower than usual.
4. There is still some error on `flutter doctor` that said flutter plugin and dart plugin is not installed. But it can build normally.